# Warum werden Präpositionen manchmal weggelassen?

Tags: preposition

Z.B. in den Sätzen:

1. Hast du Donnerstag eine Stunde Sport? (statt: am Donnerstag)
2. Ich fahre Zug. (statt: mit dem Zug)

Ist das Umgangssprache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was in Deinen Beispielen weggelassen wird, sind [Präpositionen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4position), nicht Pronomen.

Nach den Regeln der Grammatik kann man die Präpositionen "eigentlich" nicht weglassen. Es gibt seit einigen Jahrzehnten aber die Tendenz, das trotzdem zu tun, vor allem in der gesprochenen, wenig formellen Sprache. Das kann noch weiter gehen als in Deinem Beispielen, etwa

> Geht Ihr Schwimmbad?

statt

> Geht Ihr ins Schwimmbad?

Diese Veränderung der Sprache, ebenso wie andere Entwicklungen, wird oft auf das sogenannte [Kiezdeutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiezdeutsch) zurückgeführt. Das wird oft verbunden mit Vorwürfen an Immigranten und die Kinder von Immigranten, an dieser Entwicklung Schuld zu sein und die Sprache zu verhunzen ("Da sieht man doch, dass die kein richtiges Deutsch können!").

Ein [Artikel in der FAZ](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/gesellschaft/sprache-im-wandel-praeposition-ueberbewertet-13016742.html), zum Beispiel, hat sich schon vor einigen Jahren mit dem Phänomen befasst. Das Institut für deutsche Sprache und Linguistik an der Humboldt-Universität zu Berlin hat ein [Infoportal](https://www.linguistik.hu-berlin.de/de/institut/professuren/multilinguale-kontexte/kiezdeutsch-1?) zu Kietzdeutsch ins Internet gestellt.

Am Rande, es ist aber nicht immer eine ausgelassene Präposition. In Deinem zweiten Beispiel würde ich "Zug fahren" eher als zusammengesetzes Verb verstehen. Dazu gibt es analoge Konstruktionen wie "Rad fahren" oder "Auto fahren".

Comment: Auch das erste Beispiel ist keine ausgelassene Präposition, da für Zeitangaben auch einfach der Akkusativ ohne Präposition benutzt werden kann.

Comment: Ein Beispiel zu RHas Kommentar: *Hast du diese**n** Donnerstag (**den** 10.6.) Sport?*, aber *Hast du an diese**m** Donnerstag (an **dem** 10.6.) Sport?*. Die Präposition würde den Dativ verlangen, aber hier haben wir eine Zeitangabe im Akkusativ. Vgl. auch *Berlin, den 10. Juni 2021*.